# Sum up data within an array - why is my code not working?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I want to sum up all of the data within an array. I did not include the array from my class, it is here:

```
int treffer [] = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

(The array is changing because of another method, full method here (with German comments, but you should get the main idea)

```
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Schuetze{

    int treffer [] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int sum = 0;

    public Schuetze(){

    }

    public void schutze1(){

    }

    public void schuetze2(){

    }

    public void trefferEinfuegen(int pTreffer) {
        // ich gehe davon aus, dass 1-5 für die Felder übergeben wird.

        // hier wird überprüft, ob der Wert im Array überhaupt existiert. Stichwort "array out of bounds"
        if(pTreffer < 1 || pTreffer > treffer.length) {
            return; // methode beenden ohne aktion. "Nichts zurück geben"
        }
        pTreffer--; // reduziere Array Index um 1 da ein Array bei 0 anfängt.
        treffer[pTreffer]++; // erhöhe den Treffer des übergebenen Feldes.
    }

    public void datenLiefern()
    {
        for (int i : treffer)
            sum += i;

        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }
```

}

My Code is not working. It displays me the correct number first, but takes that number x2.

```
public void datenLiefern()
{
    for (int i : treffer)
        sum += i;

    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the sum to 0? Why is `sum` a field and not a local variable?

Comment: Is it possible that you call `datenLiefern` twice? anyway just add `sum = 0;` before loop.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reinitilize your `sum` variable, so it should be :

```
public void datenLiefern()  {
    sum = 0;
    for (int i : treffer)
        sum += i;

    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
}
```

However, I must admit I don't understand most of your class logic :) (why is `sum` an instance variable for ex. ?)